# Binomial coefficient system of equations

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, binomial-coefficients

> Given that ${n\choose k}=3003$ and ${n\choose k-1}=2002$, find $n$ and $k$.

How can I solve these equations without guessing/WA? I can't fully eliminate one of the variables, so I tried to break down the coefficient:
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=3003$$
$$\iff \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n+1-k)!}\cdot \frac{n+1-k}{k} = 3003$$
$$\iff 2002\cdot\frac{n+1-k}{k}=3003$$
$$\iff 5k-2n=2$$

At this point is the only way forward to guess integer solutions? It seems no matter what other route I choose now, I always get this same equation again. For example I tried using Pascal's identity.

Comment: as a help for guessing: your last equation means $k=2m$, $n=5m-1$ ($m$ an integer) and since 13 divides 1001, $n$ has to be at least 13, so  $m$ is at least 3, and $m=3$ indeed gives a solution

Answer (score 1):

You have found that
$$k=\frac{2(n+1)}{5},$$
so $n=5m+4$ for some integer $m$ and then $k=2m+2$. Note that
$$\tbinom{n}{k-1}=2002=2\times7\times11\times13,$$
so $n\geq13$ and hence $m\geq2$. If $m>2$ then
$$2002=\binom{n}{k-1}=\binom{5m+4}{2m+1}>\binom{14}{5}.$$

Comment: And ${14\choose 5}=2002$, hence the last line is a contradiction. One should also show that ${5m+4\choose 2m+1}$ is increasing, but it's not difficult.

Comment: In general - it's an interesting question whether 2 such values (when not contradicting) define the solution uniquely. I haven't inverstigated it but would guess that there could be cases when more than one pair of binomial coefficients satisfy a given pair of values.